# Trying to load list of repositories by name from GitHub in JSON format

Tags: json, swift, api, github

I'm try to do `HTTP` request to take list of repositories from `GitHub` in `JSON` format.

This is for my app that will contain list of repositories and function to search repo for name.

```swift
import Foundation

class NetworkService {

    private init() {}

    static let shared = NetworkService()

    func getData(matching query: String, completionHandler: @escaping (Any) -> ()) {
        let session = URLSession.shared
        var searchUrlComponents = URLComponents()
        searchUrlComponents.scheme = "https"
        searchUrlComponents.host = "api.github.com"
        searchUrlComponents.path = "search/repositories?"
        searchUrlComponents.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "q", value: query)]
        let searchURL = searchUrlComponents.url!
        print(searchUrlComponents.url!
)

        session.dataTask(with: searchURL) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }

            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                print(json)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
            }.resume()
    }
}
```

In this part I've got error.

I'm try without  `URLComponent`, and got the same error, code look like that:

```swift
import Foundation

class NetworkService {

    private init() {}

    static let shared = NetworkService()

    func getData(matching query: String, completionHandler: @escaping (Any) -> ()) {
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let searchURL = URL(string: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q={swift}")!
        print(searchURL)


        session.dataTask(with: searchURL) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }

            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                print(json)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
            }.resume()
      }
    }
```

The error like:

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

But when I make a request in a browser with such a `URL` `("https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q={swift}")` then `JSON` is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The `path` of `URLComponents` must start with a slash and must not end with a question mark

```
searchUrlComponents.path = "/search/repositories"
```

And in the second example the URL is valid if you omit the braces

```
let searchURL = URL(string: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=swift")!
```

The reason is that unlike the browser the API `URL(string:` does not implicitly encode the URL